# SQL Server : removes null constraint when changing the column's datatype, Oracle does not

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I was reviewing something for a project and noticed in SQL Server, modifying the datatype of a column removed an existing not null check. I wanted to compare the same to Oracle and noticed that the null check is not removed when a data type change occurs.

My question: is there a reason why SQL Server does not preserve the null check without explicitly specifying the alter statement to make the column not null? After googling some, couldn't really find an answer. Maybe this is specific to a setting in SQL Server that is off?
If there isn't config, seems maybe there is a really good reason that I can't see for why this occurs.

Here is the SQL I was using to compare:

```
-- SQL Server
CREATE TABLE TestTable (Name varchar(50) NOT NULL);

-- Does not allow null
SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('dbo.TestTable', 'U'), 'Name', 'AllowsNull');

ALTER TABLE TestTable ALTER COLUMN Name varchar(250);

-- Allows null now
SELECT COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('dbo.TestTable', 'U'), 'Name', 'AllowsNull');

DROP TABLE TestTable;

-- Oracle
CREATE TABLE MYSCHEMA.TestTable (Name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL);

select nullable from all_tab_columns where owner = 'MYSCHEMA' and table_name = 'TESTTABLE' and column_name = 'NAME';
   
ALTER TABLE MYSCHEMA.TestTable MODIFY Name VARCHAR2(250);

select nullable from all_tab_columns where owner = 'MYSCHEMA' and table_name = 'TESTTABLE' and column_name = 'NAME';

Drop Table MYSCHEMA.TestTable;
```

Environment:

- SQL Server 2017
- Oracle 12c

Both running in docker on linux.

Comment: At this point just backward compatibility I imagine. It is an annoying quirk of ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN that it always sets it to NULL if not specified (independent of ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON settings) but there may be scripts that rely on it. Best to be explicit to avoid surprises

Answer (score 1):

NULL may be the default.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

> When you create or alter a table with the CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE
> statements, the database and session settings influence and possibly
> override the nullability of the data type that's used in a column
> definition. Be sure that you always explicitly define a column as NULL
> or NOT NULL for noncomputed columns.

Did you try this?

```
ALTER TABLE TestTable ALTER COLUMN Name varchar(250) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I think that is ultimately what is needed when making schema changes in sql server. After asking more folks who know way more about databases than I, I think sql server treats not null as a type and oracle treats it as a constraint. This is why the two behave differently on this topic. So yeah ensuring the defaults are set or that you keep in mind the framework when writing the SQL, should get you there!

Comment: `NOT NULL` is not a data type.  
I dislike relying on defaults.  In this case, the documentation specifically says not to.

Comment: Apologies, misspoke, didn't mean data type but rather an object type whereas oracle treats it as a constraint. I agree not to rely on defaults.